# Node js scheduled tasks are not executed after i restart the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cron, scheduled-tasks

I'm using the node-schedule library to schedule tasks in my Node.js application. The tasks are scheduled to run at specific times, but I've noticed that they work fine as long as the server remains running. However, when I restart the server, the scheduled tasks do not execute as expected.

this is my code :

```
export const createDeal = async (req, res) => {
try {
  const {
    creatorEmail,
    dealName,
    deadline,
  } = req.body;

// Create a new deal document
const newDeal = createDealDocument({
  creatorEmail,
  dealName,
  deadline,
});

// Save the deal to the database
await newDeal.save();

// Schedule a job for the deal's deadline
scheduleJob(deadline, () => {
  console.log("Deal expired for", newDeal.dealName);
  // Additional actions here, e.g., sending emails
});

return res.status(201).send({ message: "Deal created successfully", deal: newDeal });
  } catch (error) {
   return res.status(500).send({ error: error.message });
  }
 };
```

so why if i restart the server before the deadline the code inside scheduleJob will not be executed when the deadline come ? is that because i interrupted the execution of the function createDeal ? and if so does that means that the function createDeal still on execution until the deadline ?
and any other alternatives to do that please ?
thank you .

Comment: Whatever you have scheduled before shutting down the program will not execute when you start it up again unless you commit the scheduled tasks to some kind of persistent storage which is read and rescheduled again when the program starts up again. This is the same as if you were to call `setTimeout` or `setInterval`, this is only kept in memory and will vanish when you terminate the program (and that is how it should behave, imagine the headache if it didn't).

Comment: @JimNilsson thank you sir for your answer , do you propose any other approaches to do the desired work ?